# How do I output all numbers with a given amount of divisors? (C++)

Tags: c++

I need to enter 2 integers, n and k, n is the range and k is the amount of divisors for those numbers, and only display the numbers with k divisors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k,cnt=0;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>k;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
                cnt++;
        }
        if(k==cnt)
            cout<<i<<" ";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int num_divisors_i = 0; 
        for (int j = 1, len = sqrt(i); j <= len; j++) { 
            if (i % j == 0) { 
                if (i / j == j) {
                    num_divisors_i++;  
                }  
                else {
                    num_divisors_i = num_divisors_i + 2; 
                }
            } 
        } 
        if(num_divisors_i == k) cout<<i<<" has "<<k<<" divisors"<<endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How can it be done with a similar format to mine? Like without the int num_divisors(int n) and the separate int main()?

Comment: What do you mean? Everything must be inside main?

Comment: Yes, because i havent been taught this syntax yet, and i dont fully understand it

Comment: Ok, changed for all inside main.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped!

Comment: btw, what does "len" stand for and why do you need sqrt?

Comment: sqrt(num) is used to find the square root of a number. E.g. sqrt(16) is 4; So what he is doing here is find the square root of 16 and store it as len and then using it in the for condition instead of i.It's more efficient than my answer. Maybe will execute around half the time it will take for mine to execute.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int n = 0, k = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the range: ";
    std::cin >> n; if (!std::cin) throw std::runtime_error("range read failed");
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter the number divisors: ";
    std::cin >> k; if (!std::cin) throw std::runtime_error("number of divisors read failed");
    std::cout << "numbers with " << k << " divisor:: ";
    for (int i = 1; i != n+1/*if k is inclusive else n*/; ++i) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j != i+1; ++j) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                cnt += 1;
        }
        if(cnt == k)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are i!=n+1 and j!=i+1 used for?

Comment: != is equivalent to "not equal to".

Comment: yeah i know that but why add 1 to i , n and j?

Comment: for example if i=6, as soon as j = 6, the condition will fail because j == i. Therefore in other to iterate for j=6, we will have to increment i to 7. That's why there is a j != i + 1 say.